# RemoteCallbackList vs arrayList

Tags: android, aidl

```
When we use aidl ，we often use  code like this:
```

`RemoteCallbackList<IRemoteServiceCallback> mCallbacks`.

Can we use `ArrayList<IRemoteServiceCallback> mCallbacks`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a `List` same as an `ArrayList` so **YES** but you wouldn't want to as [**`RemoteCallbackList`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/RemoteCallbackList.html) does extra things for you to name 1

> Keeps track of a set of registered IInterface callbacks

and also

> If a registered callback's process goes away, this class will take care of automatically removing it from the list. If you want to do additional work in this situation, you can create a subclass that implements the onCallbackDied(E) method.

all quotes from the Documentation